# upload the file not open after upload in google cloud bucket using XHR

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I have upload the video file in google cloud storage bucket using XHR method.

i used below http header set for the video upload.

```
  $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               beforeSend: function(request) 
               {                      
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + 
                    localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
                    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'video/mp4');
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
                    request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
               url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/test/o?uploadType=media&name=testing.mp4',
  
           data:{
               uploadType:"media"
           },
           xhr: function () {
               var submit = new Date().getTime();
               var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
              return myXhr;
           },
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               
               completedata(data);
           },
           
           error: function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           },
           
           async: true,
           data: formData,
           crossDomain: true,
           cache: false,
          contentType: true,
           processData: false
       });
                  
                   
               },
```

when i visit the link from bucket file then video not play.

Link: https://storage.googleapis.com/edithouse-upload/test.mp4

can you know what i missed in video upload to the bucket ?

Comment: You have set the object headers correctly. How are you testing and what happens? Stating that the video will not play is not enough information.

Comment: @JohnHanley i have updated my code and can you please let me know what i missing ?

Comment: I see your code, but you did not answer the question part.

Comment: @JohnHanley i upload the video on storage bucket. it's stored correctly but when i copy the url and paste to the browser then video not play. this is my bucket url for video upload. https://storage.googleapis.com/edithouse-upload/test.mp4

Comment: Which browser? You state "video not play". What does happen? We should not be playing 99 questions to get details.

Comment: @JohnHanley in any browser and when i visit above url it's show blank screen with video player.

Comment: Start Chrome. Start the Chrome debugger. Enter your URL. Provide details that Chrome displays on errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley i check in chrome. it's not shown any error. i am sure i something wrong in my upload video script.

Comment: Download the object using a tool like `curl` or `wget`. Then binary compare to make sure the upload was correct.

Comment: @JohnHanley after download the video is when i try to play the video in VLC player it's show error This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

Comment: Stop guessing. Debugging problems is a science. Did you binary compare the download with the original file? If they do not match, then figure out the type of corruption which will point to what is wrong with the upload.